# From date to timestamp python

Tags: datetime, timestamp

used time and datetime.
This is timestamp 15229231800000000 i need to generate it from date 05.04.2018 13:15
tried

```
import time
import datetime

times = '05.04.2018 13:15'
timer = time.mktime(time.strptime(times, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))
timer = int(timer * 10000000)
print timer
```

but it not generate that timestamp 15229231800000000